# How to href an image from an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get an URL from an input form in the href of an image. It's not working with onkeyup. Anyone an idea what's wrong here? This is the code I'm using:

```js
//Twitter

function addtwitter()
 {
var twitter = document.getElementById("twitter");
var s =twitter.value;

document.getElementById("twimg").style.display= "inline";
document.getElementById("tw").href= s;
}

//LinkedIn

function addlinkedin()
 {
var linkedin = document.getElementById("linkedin");
var s =linkedin.value;

document.getElementById("limg").style.display= "inline";
document.getElementById("li").href= s;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div><label>Your Twitter Url:</label></div>
        <input class="inline" id="twitter" type="text" name="twitter" onKeyup="addtwitter()">
        <br>
        <div><label>Your LinkedIn Url:</label></div>
        <input class="inline" id="linkedin" type="text" name="linkedin" onKeyup="addlinkedin()">
        <br>
</form>
<br>
<div>
<span id="tw" href="#"><img id="twimg" border="0" src="http://image000.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145812.svg" width="25" height="25" alt="Twitter" style="vertical-align: middle"></span>
<span id="li" href="#"><img id="limg" border="0" src="http://image000.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145807.svg" width="25" height="25" alt="LinkedIn" style="vertical-align: middle;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use setAttribute() function to set the href value but the span will not behave as a link.
Despite of using **span** you can use **anchor tag** or you can use **anchor tag inside the span**. Below is the modified code.

Suggestion: call the **addtwitter()** and **addlinkdin()** function on **oblur** event..

```html
<form>
<div><label>Your Twitter Url:</label></div>
        <input class="inline" id="twitter" type="text" name="twitter" onblur="addtwitter()">
        <br>
        <div><label>Your LinkedIn Url:</label></div>
        <input class="inline" id="linkedin" type="text" name="linkedin" onblur="addlinkedin()">
        <br>
</form>
<br>
<div>
<a id="tw" href="#"><span><img id="twimg" border="0" src="http://image000.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145812.svg" width="25" height="25" alt="Twitter" style="vertical-align: middle"></span></a>
<a id="li" href="#"><span><img id="limg" border="0" src="http://image000.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145807.svg" width="25" height="25" alt="LinkedIn" style="vertical-align: middle;"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great - that worked! I'll have to make format restrictions so that the input url always starts with http:// - otherwise it won't work. Thanks Shambhu!

Answer (score 0):

The href is an attribute and needs to be set using the setAttribute function. Please find the corrected code below:

```
//Twitter
function addtwitter()
{
  var twitter = document.getElementById("twitter");
  var s =twitter.value;
  document.getElementById("twimg").style.display= "inline";
  document.getElementById("tw").setAttribute('href',s);
}
//LinkedIn
function addlinkedin()
{
  var linkedin = document.getElementById("linkedin");
  var s =linkedin.value;
  document.getElementById("li").setAttribute('href',s);
  document.getElementById("limg").style.display= "inline";
}
```

Hope this helps!